# How to look inside JVM(?). Can I profile methods, arguments, return values etc in working application?

Tags: java, jvm, profiling

First of all sorry for a little dummy question. I want to ask JVM professionals.

Assume that you have a working java application. Are there some JVM APIs (JVM TI) that can give me an information about what methods is being called now, what arguments do they get and what values do they return. `If yes, why there are no such testing java tools, that can rely on this information and produce jUnit tests?`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for a "debugging" environment is to download the Eclipse integrated development environment (IDE). That environment has a full debugging environment that will let you step through your program (and much more).

Go to https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ and download the one that matches your operating system.

There are many other things available in eclipse ... it will server you well for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're actually up to, but just for an overview of what a JVM is currently doing, check out the "jvisualvm" application, which is included in the JDK. If JAVA_HOME/bin is in your PATH, just typing "jvisualvm" on a command line should get you going. You will be able to see what java applications are currently running on your machine, select one, and see what it is doing in terms of memory use, method calls, and performance.
If you need even more information, use a debugger integrated with you IDE.
JUnit test are a completely different thing. Unit tests should test your code against a contract, they don't need to see what your program is doing. I suggest you read some theoretical information on unit testing first before attempting to use any advanced tools.